# Why isn't my array filled correctly?

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I am writing code for a game in Java. Specificly I'm working on the level creation using a character array filled by characters from a .txt file. My problem is that the array is not filled as it should be and the final line remains empty. I can't work this out so any kind of help will be gladly accepted, here's the problematic block of code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

char background[][] = new char [14][20];

try {

    FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream("background.txt");
        int r;
        for(int i=0;i<=13;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<19;j++){
                while((r = fileinput.read()) != -1){
                    char c = (char) r;
                    background[i][j] = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        fileinput.close();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i=0;i<=13;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=19;j++){
            System.out.print(background[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also the code as a whole can be found in the following link: http://pastebin.com/HtwMpsjm
Here's the .txt file too!

Comment: If you have an IDE with a debugger, it would be beneficial for you to learn how to debug and step through your own code.

Answer (score 4):

You accidentally one of your conditions, i've commented on the changed line.

As someone has mentioned in the comments, you might find it beneficial to treat your loops conditions as `for(int i=0;i<20;i++)` rather than `for(int i=0i<=19;i++)` it makes the code a little more readable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

char background[][] = new char [14][20];

try {

    FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream("background.txt");
        int r;
        for(int i=0;i<=13;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=19;j++){//<<THIS LINE WAS CHANGED
                while((r = fileinput.read()) != -1){
                    char c = (char) r;
                    background[i][j] = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        fileinput.close();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i=0;i<=13;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=19;j++){
            System.out.print(background[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should point out the standard way to limit for loops is <length, so in this case <14 and <20, rather than <=

Comment: Your inner loops condition for filling the array, differs from the condition outputting the array. This means your never filling `background[][19]`. But you are outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do we need multiple for loops here. If you want to read characters from a file you could use buffered reader and the this matrix could be created in one line of code like `while((bufferedReader.read(background[i]) != -1) && (++i < 14)){ }`. Also you are using a while loop to read one char and then an unconditional break statment inside is not a good practice (in my opinion). Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    char background[][] = new char[14][20];
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("background.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        int i=0;
        while((bufferedReader.read(background[i]) != -1) && (++i < 14)){ } // This like created your 2D array

        bufferedReader.close();
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 19; j++) {
            System.out.print(background[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```